# Upsampling PCMU

Tags: java, algorithm, audio, encoding, sampling

Is there an algorithm for upsampling PCMU without having to convert it to PCM first?
Are the standard interpolation algorithms applicable to PCMU encoded samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding and re-encoding mu law is very simple, and probably easier than trying to work out the potential aliasing implications of interpolating mu-law. You'll probably want to apply a low pass filter after upsampling, for which you would need to decode and re-encode anyway.

Comment: I wanted to try to avoid additional encoding/decoding for optimization purposes but you are maybe right. Sorry but I don't know what low pass filter is?

Comment: your upsampled signal should contain no high frequencies that weren't present in the original. A low pass filter attempts to remove any that might have got introduced as an unintentional side-effect of upsampling.